# What is the meaning of a low-fidelity model in the multi-fidelity Gaussian processes

Tags: bayesian, multiple-regression, modeling, gaussian-process

I'm quite interested in the topic of multi-fidelity Gaussian processes, which build a GP based on measurements with different fidelities. I have a very general question about this method.

Background: Assume that we only have two fidelities now. Why don't we just build a deterministic model for the low-fidelity measurements instead of a GP model? This question originates from some robotics papers, which assume a simplified model for the real system and use GP to learn a residual term between the model and the real-world measurements. From my understanding, this simplified model is actually a deterministic low-fidelity GP with zero variance in the context of multi-fidelity GP.

Questions:

1. If we have a discrete-time system and measurements of transition pairs between two consecutive sampling times as training data, can we always build a simplified deterministic model (even a mistakenly assumed one) serving as the low-fidelity to improve the performance of the learned discrete system (deterministic model + GP residual) compared to the purely data-driven GP model.
2. Can we get a better-performed model via the following learning method compared to using a deterministic low-fidelity model directly? The model is learned for the same system via 1. building a simplified deterministic model; 2. building a low-fidelity GP for this simplified deterministic model via sampling some point from this model; 3. building a multi-fidelity GP model comprising the low-fidelity GP and the residual GP.

Any comments are more than welcome!